# how to track traffics from multiple domains to a single website

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have 4 domains all pointed to a single WP website and i want to know which domain is getting the most traffic. how can i segregate the traffic/domain in google analytics? FYI im using "monster insights" plugin for WP.

Answer (score 0):

In short: A good solution would be to create a **tracking URL** for each of the 4 domains. Then, instead of pointing your domains to your "single website", you point each one of then to the created "tracking URL". That way you will be able to check the traffic coming as **referrals** in your google analytics reports.

Create your [tracking url here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

I recommend you use:

Website URL = http://single-website.com (Where all 4 domains are being redirected)

Campaign Source = website-name-1 (Change this name with the name of your 4 domains each time)

Campaign Medium = "Domains" (Or the name you prefer)

Campaign Name = "Redirect" (Or the name you prefer)

You can use the remaining fields, but I would only use these ones.

Result Example for domain 1:

http://single-website.com/?utm_source=website-number-1&utm_medium=domains&utm_campaign=redirect

Do the same for the remaining domains